# How to display an Image in a different Form with simple Button press

Tags: c#

I have 2 Forms. The first one contains a `Button` and the other contains a `PictureBox`.
Now I want to display the `PictureBox` when the `Button` is pressed.
I have tried with this code:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // in order to hide the first form
    this.Hide();
    Form2 f1 = new Form2();
    f1.ShowDialog();
    // to display the pic the second form            
    Form2.pictureBox1.Visible = true;
}
```

But the problem was that it was inaccessible due to protection level.
What can I do?

Comment: What do you mean with *I am using VB.net (c#)*? The code you're showing is C#, not VB.Net. Pick one, different languages. -- Having an instance of `Form2` created as `Form2 f1 = new Form2();`, you will then be accessing a Control in `Form2` with `f1.PictureBox.Visible = true;`.. **Before** `.ShowDialog();`. -- An instance of `Form2` named as `f1` can be quite confusing.

Comment: oh sorry about that i meant c#

Comment: Ok i tried that it said form 1 does not contain definition for 'pictureBox1' and no extension method for 'pictureBox1'.

Comment: Apparently, `pictureBox1` is in `Form2`, not `Form1`. A piece of the code you have written is not correct. When something *is not working*, post the code you're actually using, updating you question.

Comment: yes its in form 2 and thanks

Answer (score 0):

One Way is to Pass the Image Path (string) as argument to Form2. i.e. Create a constructor for Form2 taking a string param. Do the Image Assignment & Visibility thing in Form2 Constructor (obvisouly after InitializeComponents()).

Hack Fix way is to make the PictureBox in Form2 (designer) as Public.

Comment: sorry but am still new to this how can i do that, i changed the picBox to public ok, and created the constructor but still the problem remains